# Can't seem to figure out how to use response headers in Flask

Tags: python, flask, header, response

Hey guys idk why my code is not working. I forgot most of the stuff about response headers and how to use it and i suck at figuring out when to use dict and tuple etc.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, request, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('Config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
response = {}

class JsonModel(object): #Class for making objects JSON serializable
    def as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

class User(db.Model, JsonModel): #Class which is a model for the User table in the database
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    LastName = db.Column(db.String(20))

def __init__(self,User_ID,FirstName, LastName):
    self.User_ID = User_ID
    self.FirstName = FirstName
    self.LastName = LastName

class Todo(db.Model, JsonModel):    #Class which is a model for the Todo table in the database
    todo_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.User_ID"))
    details = db.Column(db.String(30))

def __init__(self, UserID, details):
    self.UserID = UserID
    self.details = details

@app.route('/todo', methods = ['GET'])   #Uses GET method to return all information in the database.
def index():
    return json.dumps([u.as_dict() for u in Todo.query.all()])

@app.route('/todo/<int:todo_ID>', methods = ['GET'])
def get(todo_ID):
    todo = Todo.query.get(todo_ID)
    response
    response['todo_ID']= todo.todo_ID
    response['UserID'] = todo.UserID
    response['details'] = todo.details
    response.status_code = 200
    response.headers['location'] = '/todo/{}'.format(todo.todo_ID)
    return response
```

WHen running this code I get the following error.

```
File "/home/muba/PycharmProjects/Work/Flaskapp.py", line 43, in get
    response.status_code = 200
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2017 21:29:27] "GET /todo/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong and also point me to some sort of tutorial. Only thing I can understand from this is that my response object at the top can't use status_code for some reason.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Return a JSON object?

Comment: I'm trying to return all the details of a specific todo, and also add more information to it using the response headers when i use a curl statement. I threw it in an object hoping that it would work. It was working at one point now it doesn't.

Comment: I want to return nothing. When i run the curl statement I just want the location to be shown as well since it normally doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're looking to return the `todo` object in JSON format; below is a simplified example of constructing a response with the JSON object and extra headers.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
    def index():

    todo = {'todo_ID': 1, 'UserID': 2, 'details': 'test'}
    r = make_response((json.dumps(todo),
                       200,
                       {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'location': '/todo/{}'.format(todo['todo_ID'])}))
    return r


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**curl response:**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json 
Location: http://localhost:5000/todo/1
Content-Length: 46
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.13
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 09:09:11 GMT


* Closing connection 0 
{"UserID": 2, "details": "test", "todo_ID": 1}
```

Comment: He can just use jsonify instead of make_response in my opinion. Jsonify automatically sets the content-type header of the response object

Comment: @megadarkfriend is it possible to set extra headers with jsonify?

Comment: I don't believe so. The content-type header is set to application/json when using jsonify. Here are the docs for more reference: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify

Comment: It looks like @tony wants to add the location header to the response so jsonify won't work here.

Comment: I'm confused af, I was looking at my code again. Is the error the object has no attribute status_code happening because im using response object to get the Todo details and it's telling me theres no such thing as status_code in todo table?

Comment: Your `response` object is just an ordinary dict object, it doesn't have an attribute `status_code` for you to set.

Comment: isn't there someone way to give it the attribute then.

Comment: Yes, you would just do as follows `response['status_code'] = 200` however you can't return a dict object from a Flask view

Comment: actually now that I think about it, should my GET method return the details that I get? I'm still new to this and have been making assumptions.

Comment: In general, yes. A client calling the endpoint would typically want to retrieve details of the resource. In that case it makes sense to return a JSON object like I originally suggested. I will revert my answer.